# Missing assembly reference or directive for TwitterResponse

Tags: c#, twitter

TwitterResponse response = TwitterStatus.Update( accesstoken, "Testing!! It works (hopefully).");

Comment: using Twitterizer;
using TwitterOAuth;
using Twitterizer.Entities;           i have included them as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the reference

```
using Twitterizer; 
using TwitterOAuth; 
using Twitterizer.Entities;
```

in your case.

**Update**

Copy the downloaded **twitterizer dll** file in a custom folder on your dev drive,
 then add the reference to your project using the Browse button in the **Add Reference dialog.**

Be sure that the new reference has the Copy **Local = True.**

The Add  Reference dialog could be opened right-clicking on the References item in your project in Solution Explorer

Comment: Please add the dll in your  reference

Comment: That is what, Add the dll reference in you project by right clicking Reference option on the right side of your visual studio

Comment: Install-Package twitterizer -Version 2.4.1   i have tried downloading it from package manger console                           CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
                                        i have tried to search from nuget package as well it was not able to search as well

Comment: use this link and download   twitterizer.framework.dll  http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_elefantpp/downloads/Elefant/Twitterizer.Framework.dll/

Comment: http://www.dll4you.com/files/Twitterizer.Framework.dll.html  or http://www.filewatcher.com/m/Twitterizer.Framework.dll.31232-0.html